# Как правильно верстать лендинг

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В выделенном блоке задавать фиксированную высоту или использовать padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от пожеланий менеджера и дизайнера:

- а) использовать paadding, поскольку контента может быть больше и блок
  должен менять размер;
- б) может быть лендинг должен быть адаптивным, и    каждый блок должен
  быть на весь монитор на всех расширениях, как    например на сайтах
  Microsoft